# Changing shipping options using the Google Checkout Shopping Cart

Tags: google-checkout

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question, so I asked on StackOverflow as well. But,

Is it possible to set the shipping options in Google Checkout without using the server-server submission option?

I'm trying to keep this checkout process as simple as possible (mostly because I do not fully understand the server-server API section), and therefore I'm using the direct submission option in Google Checkout (details [here](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API.html#create_checkout_cart). scroll down past the code block). So, I'd like to just add the hidden input fields to designate how much shipping will cost, and send it along.

Is this possible?

If this doesn't belong on WebApps, let me know and I'll close it.

[Shipping options documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API.html#shipping_xsd)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes It's in "Option A" of your first link under "Sending Order Information ..."  When you create your google checkout button HTML you will just include the correct shipping  tags that specify the shipping options that you support.

Once you create a regular Google Checkout Button you will add the hidden shipping input tags.